# Why does "unowned self" in closure not work correctly in Swift?

Tags: closures, swift

Code following in Apple's Swift language official guide:

```
class HTMLElement {

    let name: String
    let text: String?

    @lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        [unowned self] in
        if let text = self.text {
            return "<\(self.name)>\(text)</\(self.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self.name) />"
        }
    }

    init(name: String, text: String? = nil) {
        self.name = name
        self.text = text
    }

    deinit {
        println("\(name) is being deinitialized.")
    }
}
```

Use capture list with `unowned` in closure to avoid retain cycle. We demo it:

```
var paragraph: HTMLElement? = HTMLElement(name: "p", text: "Hello, world!")
println(paragraph!.asHTML())        
paragraph = nil
```

The result should be

```
<p>Hello, world!</p>
p is being deinitialized.
```

Last line is important because it told us `paragraph` was deinitialized expectedly, but the actual result was

```
<p>Hello, world!</p>
```

The last line didn't appear. Memory leaked. This is the ORIGINAL code in official guide.The `unowned` didn't work correctly?
So I used `weak` rather than `unowned` to test what would happen:

```
...
    @lazy var asHTML: () -> String = {
        [weak self] in
        if let text = self?.text {
            return "<\(self?.name)>\(text)</\(self?.name)>"
        } else {
            return "<\(self?.name) />"
        }
    }
...
```

The result was exactly what we want. Console displayed `p is being deinitialized.` 
I can't understand what's wrong with me or the original code in guide made a mistake or else?

Comment: Is this in the playground? Playground memory scope is a bit different and weird

Comment: I experienced the same issue in the Playground when running through the book the first time, works as expected in a compiled running app

Comment: I tested in typical project environment, not playground

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** This is now fixed in xcode 6 beta 3:

> • unowned class references will no longer sometimes retain their
>   target. (16980445)

---

In the Xcode 6 beta 2 release notes posted yesterday, it mentions:

> • unowned class references sometimes retain their target. (16980445)

under Known Issues in Xcode 6 Beta 2.

Comment: Yeah, its still under beta so you should report anything like this through bug reports. the fact that its a "known issue" means that other people have reported it. Even then, you should still report it to let them know thats its important!